# JavaScript bookmarklet code to get URL of tab that was launched from current tab

Tags: javascript, url, tabs, bookmarklet

I am trying to develop a bookmarklet. The purpose of the bookmarklet is to display the URL of both the current tab and the new tab that was launched as a result of a `window.open` call. To simplify things, assume that the `launcher.com` launches a random URL to visit.

```
function getBothURLs() { 
    var currentURL, newWin;

    function launchNew () {
        currentURL = window.location.href; 
        newWin     = window.open("https://www.launcher.com");
    }

    launchNew();
    alert(currentURL); 
    alert(newWin.location.href); // displays 'about:blank'
}
```

I am unable to get the URL of the newly launched tab. The `alert()` (at the very end of the function below) does not correctly display the newly launch tab's URL; instead it displays

```
 about:blank
```

When I was troubleshooting this within the Chrome console, I moved the definition of `var currentURL, newWin` to outside the scope of the `getTwoURLs()` function. When I invoked the function `getBothURLs()` from within the console, both `currentURL` and `newWin` had valid data.

How should the function `getBothURLs()` be modified to achieve the desired purpose?

Comment: Better you can add the random url value into a variable like:  newUrl = "https://www.google.com", then assign the value to newWin variable like: newWin = window.open(newUrl);

After doing this try to put the below line:  
alert(newUrl);   

I hope it will work.

Comment: I assume that you are opening a url on a different origin. Do you have access to the the codebase of other url? @AntonySUTHAKARJ's comment makes sense, could you explain why that wont work for you?

Comment: For all practical purposes, the URL is being opened on the same origin. But it is not known ahead of time since the URL will include an auto-generated hexadecimal number as part of it.

Comment: Is there a reason not to pass in `urlToOpen` as a parameter to `getBothURLs`? I'm thinking there ought to be a function with inputs and outputs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note on [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) from MDN:

> ...remote URLs **won't load immediately**. When *window.open()* returns, the window always contains **about:blank**. The actual fetching of the URL is **deferred** and starts after the current script block finishes executing...

In the above case the *current* blocks ends with the `getBothURLs()` function, but you attempt to check the new URL within that block itself, and according to the quote above, you see the `about:blank` url.
To fix this just defer the lookup until the next task. You can use something like `setTimeout` to *post* the lookup onto the next task or, even better, use Promises if you wish to return the value from the function.

A sample implementation could look like:

```
function getBothURLs() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var newWin = window.open("//www.stackoverflow.com");
    setTimeout(() => resolve(newWin))
  }).then((win) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       var check = setInterval(() => {
         try { 
           if(win.location.href !== "about:blank"){
               clearInterval(check);
               resolve(win.location.href)
           }
         } catch(e) {
           clearInterval(check);
           reject(e);
         }
       }, 50)
     })
   })
}

getBothURLs().then(url => console.log(url))
```

Although, the above mentioned solution works, I would still recommend that you store new window's URL in a variable and then call `open` with that variable.

#### Update 1:

This example snippet uses the non-promise callback version that could return both the urls. Although, it's possible to modify the promise version to return two urls as well but since the OP asked for a non-promise based version in the comments so I provided the new snippet.
Have a look:

```
function getBothURLs(callback){
  var current = window.location.href;
  var win = window.open("https://stackoverflow.com");
  var check =  setInterval(() => {
    try {
      if(win.location.href !== "about:blank"){
        clearInterval(check);
        callback(null, current, win.location.href)
      }
    } catch(e) {
      clearInterval(check);
      callback(e);
    }
  }, 50);
}

getBothURLs((err, _cur, _new) => {
  if(err){
    // some error occurred, probably a cross-origin access
    console.error("Failed to get URL", err);
    return;
  }

  console.log(`Current: ${_cur} New: ${_new}`);
})
```

Comment: This code goes into a continuous loop when there is cross-origin links. 
Secondly, it doesn't return both the URLs (it only returns the new URL). And , good to know what Promise can do, but isn't that an overkill for this?

Comment: @lifebalance Good catch! I've fixed the snippet to handle error checking and prevent the infinite loop, but I would like to point a previous comment on the OP where you've mentioned that - "..For all practical purposes, the URL is being opened on the same origin" - and so I didn't include that in the earlier revision, nvm though, a little error-checking is always good

Comment: @lifebalance and as far as the Promise is concerned, I think my solution uses *async* methods to check for the url (setInterval and all) and so you need some way to notify the caller when you are done, and so I used Promise here... you can also opt in for Callbacks if you like...

Comment: Thanks for the fix. How can the function be made to return both the URLs?

Comment: If it isn't too much trouble, would help to know the non-Promise callback version as well.